# How to make a paste button instead of long press

Tags: java, android, copy-paste

I made a button to copy the edit text content, then i want to past it in a webview with a button not with a long press, i know how to get the copied text from the clipboard but i don't know how i can replace the long press to show the past button

Comment: You should first read this one [Copy and Paste](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste#java)

Comment: I did it didn't help :/